# InfoWindowsAdapter not fire on monondroid

Tags: xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I use this code for implementing `IInfoWindowAdapter` on google maps android version 2.

```
public class myInfoWindowsAdapter : GoogleMap .IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    public myInfoWindowsAdapter () 
    {
    }

    public View GetInfoContents(Marker marker){
        Console .WriteLine ("Hello");
        return null ;
    }

    public View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker){
        Console .WriteLine ("HHHHH");
        return null;
    }
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose (){
    }


}
```

And use this like below:

```
    mapView .SetInfoWindowAdapter (new myInfoWindowsAdapter ());
```

but when I clike on a marker the `GetInfoContents` or `GetInfoWindow` never fired by map. Any body knows what is wrong?

Comment: I tried to implement IOnCameraChangeListener but it not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
  public class myInfoWindowsAdapter : Java .Lang .Object , GoogleMap .IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    public myInfoWindowsAdapter () 
    {
    }

    public View GetInfoContents(Marker marker){
        Console .WriteLine ("Hello");
        return null ;
    }

    public View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker){
        Console .WriteLine ("HHHHH");
        return null;
    }



}
```